# Active Class is not being applied to host element using directive

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a directive for scrolling page when menu is clicked and apply active class when page is scrolled.

First i tried page scroll on menu clicked and its working but my problem is like active class is not being applied correctly in host element. Below is my line of code

**component**

```
courses = [
    {label: 'JS', name: 'js',type:[
      {label:'Angular',name:'angular'},
      {label:'React Js',name:'reactjs'},
      {label:'Node Js',name:'nodejs'},
    ]},
  ]
```

**.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let course of courses">
    <li>{{course.name}}</li>
  <ul *ngIf="course.type">
    <li *ngFor="let type of course.type" appScroll>
      {{type.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

**directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appScroll]'
})
export class ScrollDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  @HostBinding('class.active') isActive: boolean
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick() {
    const parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode
    let node = parentNode.firstElementChild;
    while (node) {
      if (node !== this.el.nativeElement)
      {
        console.log(node)
        this.renderer.removeClass(node, 'active')
      }
        node = node.nextElementSibling;
    }

    //  for setting active class to current element
    this.isActive = true
  }

}
```

On First time its working means when i click first time on each menu its applies active class to clicked menu and removes active class from all siblings (if any has) but on clicking again active class is not being applies

I am able to achieve by below line of code

```
this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'active')
```

but i am curious to know why it worked first time with `this.isActive = true` and not worked second time

Example demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pcwunt?embed=1&file=src/app/scroll.directive.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're removing the class using `Renderer2`. When Angular removes  the class from the siblings, the `isActive` property for that element doesn't change. So when you click second time onwards, Angular thinks that it doesn't need to update the template because nothing has changed.

Instead of using `HostBinding`, write `this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'active')` in the first line of the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way i can access sibling directive in angular ? like isActive property of sibling element's directive?

Comment: You could use `ViewChildren` in your component.

Comment: yes but can i but can it be done in directive itself as we can access siblings so can we access directives as well?

Comment: Well, you can set up a static property and store all the instances in the your directive.